# jQuery: Get Child object with specific ID

Tags: jquery, selector

First some HTML:

```
<div id="tmcl-request" class="tmcl-request" style="display: none">
Request:
<b> Node: </b><span id="node">33947</span>
</div>
```

Than some JavaScript:

```
$request = $('#tmcl-request');
$newrequest = $request.clone();
```

And now the question: I want to change the inner HTML of the `<span id="node">` from the `$newrequest` object.

How to do this?

Thanks,
Bigbohne

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('#tmcl-request').find('#node').html('whatever you want your html to be');
```

Thought, if you will have multiple nodes it's better to use a class instead of an id, so

```
$newrequest.find('#node').html('your html');
```